# Angular2: Exporting a custom HTTP request class

Tags: angular, typescript

I wrote a little HTTP requests class with Angular 2:

```
http-handler.ts

import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http'
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class HttpHandler {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    post(url, _body) {
        let body = JSON.stringify(_body);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(url, body, options)
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => res.json())
    }

    get(url) {
        return this.http.get(url)
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => res.json())
    }
}
```

I want to use it with a file that's bootstrapped:

```
login.component.ts

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http'

import {HttpRequest} from './http-handler'

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component({
    selector: 'loginForm',
    template:`<some html>`,
})

export class LoginComponent extends HttpRequest {

    login(event) {
        var credentials = {
            "username": this.username, // username put in a form
            "password": this.password  // password put in a form
        }

        this.post('http://localhost/login', credentials) // method from http-handler.ts file
            .then(result => {
                if (result.correct) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('username', this.username);
                    window.location = 'welcome.html';
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
                else {

                }
            })

    }
}
```

Now all I get is an error from `http-handler.ts`: `this.http is undefined`. When I paste all the methods from `http-handler.ts` to `login.component.ts`, the code works perfectly. Do you know what can be wrong?

Comment: You export the class `HttpHandler` but import `HttpRequest`? - Maybe that's a typo, but try to add a constructor to `LoginComponent` with `(protected http: Http)`  and change the http-param of your `HttpHandler`-constructor to `protected` as well

Answer (score 0):

But what's the reason to do that?.

if you want to change the header you can do something like this.

```html
    export class baseRequestOption extends BaseRequestOptions {

    constructor(private _authService?:AuthService) {
        super();
        var token = this._authService.token;
        if (token) {
            this.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);       
            this.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        } else {            
            this.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        }

    }
}
@Injectable()
export class BaseHttpService {

 http: Http;
 constructor(http: Http,private _authService:AuthService) {
        this.http = http;
        this.http._defaultOptions = new baseRequestOption(this._authService);

 }

}
```

`